# Spring + AJAX fail to connect

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, connection

I recently meet a bug that AJAX can't connect to Spring Boot. The resources/draw/index.html:

```
 function saveTagForPart(imageID, x1, x2, y1, y2, description){
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/workplace/part/save",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{
        imageID : imageID,
        x1: x1,
        x2: x2,
        y1: y1,
        y2: y2,
        description : description
    },

    success : function (data) {
        if(data.success){
            alert("Success saved for part picture !");
        }
        else
            alert("Error savedd for part picture !");
    },

    error : function () {
        alert("Network warning for saving part picture !");
    }

});}
var draw_tag = function () {
var tagX = startX<endX?startX:endX;
var tagY = startY<endY?startY:endY;

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.font = "20px Verdana";
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fillText($('#label-tag').val(),tagX,tagY);
var s= $('.canvas_container').css('background').substring(0).search("images/");
var e= $('.canvas_container').css('background').substring(0).search(".png");
var imageID = $('.canvas_container').css('background').substring(s+7,e);
saveTagForPart(imageID, startX, endX, startY, endY, $('#label-tag').val());};
```

In Spring Boot TagController.java:

```
@RestController("/workplace/part/")
public class TagPartController {
    TagPartService tagPartService = new TagPartServiceImpl();
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response<Boolean> saveTagPart(String imageID, double x1, double x2,     double y1, double y2, String description) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Get saved");
        System.out.println(imageID);
        return tagPartService.saveTagPart(imageID, x1, x2, y1, y2, description);
}
```

I try to check whether the URL, HTTP, or the data itself, but it all occurs right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your url pattern with @RequestMapping instead of @RestController.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workplace/part/")
public class TagPartController {
    TagPartService tagPartService = new TagPartServiceImpl();
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response<Boolean> saveTagPart(String imageID, double x1, double x2,     double y1, double y2, String description) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Get saved");
        System.out.println(imageID);
        return tagPartService.saveTagPart(imageID, x1, x2, y1, y2, description);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the fronted... orz